# MySQL log reader

Tags: mysql, logging

So, I'm trying to analyse some of my program's MySQL queries. However, while I've got MySQL general query logging turned on, and can view the log file in a text editor (eg. notepad++), the program writes 1000s of lines of query a minute, so I could do with a slightly better program for reading the logs. Things that would be nice:

- Better syntax highlighting.
- Real-time updating.
- doesn't get too slow when looking at long files
- Handles random binary sequences in the log without breaking

Any suggestions?

**Edit**: Windows-7 compatible programmes only

Comment: I typically just `tail -f` the log. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, from testing out a bunch of programmes, the best option I've found is [baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/), which has good real-time updating and handles large files reasonably well. It could do with better MySql-specific syntax, but it's not bad.

Alternatively, it turns out that there are actually options in [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (in preferences: misc) to turn on real-time updating, but this doesn't work well unless you have focus on the notepad++ window

There's also a windows implementation of [tail](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: INMO, Navicat Monitor is a better tool and easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `tail -f <file_path>`. That will follow the log as it's appended to.

Additionally, you could give [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) a try. It supports syntax highlighting (through regex).

Answer (score 0):

[pt-query-digest](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-query-digest.html) from the Percona Toolkit (= Maatkit, but Maatkit will not be developed any further, so switch to the Percona Toolkit). Don't use as a 'live' inspector though, but just as a bulk tool.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql log tables like general log and slow query log.

Update your mysql config file with:

```
general_log=1
slow_query_log=1
slow-launch-TIME = 2
log-output = TABLE
```

**OR**

You can use [**MySQL Administrator**](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives.php?p=mysql-administrator-suite&o=-win) to view logs(general log, slow query log, error log).

**OR**

You can also view that log file using [**TextPad**](http://www.textpad.com/download/index.html) software. It can support a file more than a GB to read write.